# How to clear android studio logcat in Arctic Fox 3.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

In the latest Arctic Fox Version of AS the "bin icon" to clear the logcat disappeared.
Is this a bug or was it moved somewhere else?

In previous versions of AS it was on the upper-left corner.

[image]

Comment: Working on Android or Flutter?

Comment: Currently on Android